# Поводов или поводьев?

Tags: падежи, родительный-падеж

What is the genitive case plural (Родительный падеж множественного числа) for **ПОВОД** (случай)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **поводов**.

**Поводьев** is the genitive of a pluralia tantum (=no singular, like "scissors") noun **поводья**, meaning "reins".

EDIT: People have pointed out in the comments that **поводья** does get used in the singular, and I stand corrected. It's rather a case of having two plurals according to the meaning, as with **лист** => **листы** "sheets" or **листья** "leaves". In my defense, **поводов** is likely the only form you're ever going to need to remember, and when you do come across the word in its "horse" sense it's likely to already be in the **-ья** plural.

Comment: Noun _поводья_ (reins) isn't pluralia tantum. It apparently has singular form _повод_, which fully coincides with _повод_ (reason/occasion), unless plural form is taken into consideration.

Comment: Is there any difference between вожжи and поводья? (other than the fact that вожжи seems to be much more commonly used) PS, во́жжи apparently has a singular form вожжа́, according to the dictionary.

Comment: @ghostarbeiter `во́жжи apparently has a singular form вожжа́` Certainly, I always loved that expresion: "вожжа под хвост попала". BTW. it explains also how _вожжи_ are different from _поводья_: "вожжи" are larger and may be used for slapping a horse, while "поводья" only serve for turning its head.

Comment: "Вести лошадь в поводỳ" - singular from "поводья". Nowdays horse terminology is not widely known among native speakers, though lots of idioms are known, such as "идёт на поводỳ".

Comment: @ghostarbeiter: _вожжи_ is a part of a harness, they are attached near the horse's back and used when the horse is pulling a vehicle. _Поводья_ is a part of a bridle, they go to the bit (which is in horse's mouth) and are used when the horse is carrying a rider.

Answer (score 6):

There are different meanings of the word-- *one of the reins",a long, narrow strap attached at one end to a horse’s bit, typically used in pairs to guide or check a horse in riding or driving*, and *a cause,a reason*.

1. ПО́ВОД, -а, предл. о по́воде, в поводу́; мн. ***пово́дья, поводьев*** м. Ремень, прикреплённый к удилам и служащий для управления лошадью. Вести лошадь за поводья. Натянуть поводья. Держать лошадь на поводу.
   ◊ Идти (быть) на поводу́ у кого. Действовать по чьей-л. указке, не самостоятельно, быть зависимым в своих поступках от кого-л. Ты у него на поводу! Идти на поводу общественного мнения.
   ◁ Поводок; Поводковый; Поводочный (см.).
2. ПО́ВОД, -а; мн. **по́воды-поводов**; м. Случай, обстоятельство, факт, могущие быть основанием для чего-л., причиной чего-л.; предлог (1.П.). П. для ссоры. П. для серьёзного разговора. П. поругаться, помириться. Найти п. к сближению. Искать п. высказаться. Спорить по всякому (любому) поводу, без повода. Дать (подать) п. кому-л., чему-л. (дать основание, возможность поступать каким-л. образом).
   ◁ По по́воду кого-чего. в зн. предлога. 1. Относительно кого-, чего-л. Решение по поводу премьерного фильма. Высказаться по поводу результатов голосования. -2. По причине, из-за чего-л., вследствие чего-л. Волноваться по поводу задержки поезда.
   Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт С. А. Кузнецов. 1998